# Proving that f is measurable if g is measurable where $g(x, y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I need help understanding the proof of this question. Basically it involves Fubini's theorem and I can't seem to get a grasp on the proof (and I am pretty sure this question uses techniques from the proof). The question is as follows:

Assume $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is measurable and define $g: [0, 1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by  $g(x, y) := |f(x) - f(y)|$. Prove that $f$ is integrable if and only if $g$ is integrable.

Proof.
The slice of $g$, $g_x(y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$ is integrable **iff** $h(y) = f(x) - f(y)$ is integrable and $h(y)$ is integrable **iff** $f$ is integrable. $(*)$

Now, assume $g$ is integrable. If $g$ is integrable, then by Fubini's theorem, the slice $g_x$ is integrable for almost all $x$. If the slice is integrable then $(*)$ shows that $f$ is integrable.

Now assume $f$ is integrable. Then again by $(*)$ $g_x$ is integrable $\forall x$. Also, $$\int f - |f(x) \leq \int |f(x) - f(y)| dy \leq |f(x)| + \int f \qquad (**)$$

Then the function $\alpha(x) = \int |f(x) - f(y)| dy$ is bounded and measurable and therefore integrable on $[0, 1]$. By Fubini we have $\int g = \int \int |f(x) - f(y)| dy dx = \int \alpha(x) dx$ hence $g$ is integrable.

Now my question(s) are:

- How did $(*)$ come about? It seems intuitive to me to claim that but can someone explain to me why that is the case?
- In the forward direction (assuming f is true), how can the claim that $g_x$ be integrable hold for ALL x?
- And where is the $(**)$  coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first point, suppose first that $f(y)$ is integrable, then $h(y)$  is integrable because it is the difference of two integrable functions (note that $f(x)$ is a constant w.r.t. $y$ and constants are integrable since $[0,1]$ has finite measure). Conversely, if $h(y)$ is integrable, then $f(y)=h(y)+f(x)$ is integrable, because it is the sum of two integrable functions.

For the second point, if $f$ is integrable then $h(y)$ is integrable for every $x$ (for what we have showed before) so that $g_x(y)$ is integrable for every $x$.

The third point follows from mookid's answer, but you need to substitute $\int f$ with $\int |f|$.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Could you expand on "constants are integrable since [0, 1] has finite measure". 

Edit: Spoke too soon. Ofcourse they are. Constants can be characterized by the characterisic function. The integral of a characteristic function is simply the measure of the set.

Comment: Yeah, you're right!

Comment: Okay, one last question which may be a stupid question. If $h(y)$ is integrable, what is the reason that the absolute value of that is integrable, ie $g_x(y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$ On the other hand, if we have $g_x$ integrable, if we remove the absolute bars, can we be guaranteed that it would still be integrable?

Comment: Ah, my definition of integrability for an arbitrary real-valued function is that  $f$ is integrable if and only if $|f|$ is integrable. You have a different one?

Comment: I have the same one. Its just that I have 4 different ones (we did definition of simple, bounded, non bounded, general functions in that order). Although my definition only has it one way. ie $f$ is integrable if $|f|$ is integrable.

Comment: Ok, then, do you still have doubts?

Comment: Nope, Im okay. Thanks. I've moved on to understanding $(**)$ but that seems easy enough. I've marked your answer the the correct one even thuough mookid's was good, I just needed more explanation.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy that I could help.

Comment: Actually, if I can bother you with one more. I don't understand the last inequality. It dosnt seem to match the triangle inequality (or the reverse triangle inequality). In your answer you say you have to replace $\int f$ with $\int |f|$ but are we allowed to do that? edit: OMG. ofcourse, f is integrable <-> |f| is integrable lol.

Comment: Sure: the inequality $|f(y)-f(x)|\leq |f(x)|+|f(y)|$ is the triangle inequality, and the other is still the triangle inequality applied to $f(y)=[f(y)-f(x)]+f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

- Both first points come from the characterization:
  $$
  f\text{ is measurable} \iff \forall c: \{ x:f(x)<c \}\text{ is measurable}
  $$
- the last one comes from the inequality
  $$
  |f(y)| - |f(x)| \le |f(y) - f(x)| \le |f(y)| + |f(x)|
  $$

Comment: Thanks. The last one is the reverse triangle inequality, correct?

Comment: this is the first one actually.